# IIS7 Rewrite Image Files

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, isapi

I'm wondering if it is possible to have an IIS7 URL rewrite rule that does something like this. When someone goes to:

http://www.mydomain.com/images/0000022_0-Hello_World.jpeg

it will request the file at:
http://www.mydomain.com/images/0000022_0.jpeg

I tried to make a rule to match (.*)/images/(.*)-(.*).jpeg and then rewrite it to {R:1}/images/{R:2}.jpeg, but it doesn't work. I just get a 404 error. I also tried adding the ISAPI Wildcard, but it didn't change anything.

I'm using .net 4.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use IIS Manager ( like in [this article](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/)):

Try to create a *rewrite* rule which matches the following *pattern* (regular expressions):

```
^images/([0-9_]+)-.*\.jpeg$
```

As *Action*, choose *rewrite*, and fill in the following *rewrite Url*:

```
images/{R:1}.jpeg
```

No other rule should be executed after that (-> *Stop processing of subsequent rules* checkbox)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add the ISAPI Wildcard for this as you have an extension (.jpeg) so should be handled by the StaticFile Handler.

Answer (score 0):

You should put this after other rewrite rules ,for virtual folders etc..

```
<rule name="rule 1s" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="\.(gif|jpe?g|png|bmp)"  ignoreCase="true" />
   <conditions>
       <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Rewrite" url="//ressources/default.png"  />
</rule>
```